# Why aren't some helpfully flagged questions closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, helpful-flags

Take, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17556693/), in which it is not clear what the asker is asking. I had flagged this question as "unclear what you're asking" which was deemed helpful, but apparently no action has been taken on it. Why hasn't the question been placed on hold, or are there close votes on it, but not enough to place it on hold?

Comment: @OldCheckmark that is a somewhat dated duplicate given the behavior is different now

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your flag was a **recommend closure** flag. Moderators do not see these- they go to the Close Votes queue. They get dismissed as helpful once the **first person agrees with you** and votes to close the question. Review then continues from that point with a close vote on the question instead of a flag.

There are currently four close votes on that question, and [review is still active](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2474614).

Comment: If just one pro-vote is needed to the flag be considered "helpful", does it mean the disputed flags are over, now?

Comment: @AndreSilva Flags are only marked disputed when another user flags them as invalid flags. That can only happen from the 10k tools, as far as I know, and these flags don't appear there either.

Comment: The difference now, @AndreSilva, is that if a flagged post gets 3 "Do Not Close" responses in /review, it'll be *declined*. The disputed status still exists for other scenarios (indeed, it's relied on pretty heavily for Low Quality flags), but closing is something the community should be able to determine.

Comment: Thanks, for clarifying, animuson and @Shog9.